# jquery select elements with some attribute with the value

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to select the elements use the value of an attribute, however, the attribute with this value can be anything eg. href, action, id.
so, how can I select those elements?

**Update:**
In fact, I cannot find any example in this question, but it seems need to post some code to clear the question. So I try.
there is a JSON format data which contains a reference attribute. And I need to find elements which contains this reference. However, the element which be referenced to don't contain the reference attribute, the reference can be a href of an a tag element, also can be an action of a form, mostly, value of reference will appear more than one element in a page.

following code trying to find those elements

```
if(typeof reference != 'undefined'){
   $('[href="+reference+"]')
   $('[action="+reference+"]')
}
```

can I use one line to do this?

Comment: No attempt... no code... meet us half way here.

Comment: you can do this by using J query selector, Is there a piece of code that is not working ?

Comment: @Utkanos because I can not find that method in the API document, so there is no code, sorry

Comment: `href` and `action` are attribute names, not values. So can you clarify precisely what you want to do? Please edit the question to give an example.

Comment: @Utkanos I update the post, maybe now it's more clear.

Comment: @Vivek I know, I can use the attribute selector to do this, but the attribute selector is for the exactly attribute with a value, now I need to select for the exactly value of some attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I think what your after is a way to select an element that has *any* attribute with a particular value.

There's no wild-card way to specify the name of the attribute (as far as I know), but if you can cope with listing out possible attribute names (as you hint with your code) then the way to do it would be like this :

```
var selecteds = $(
    '[href="' + reference + '"]' + 
    ', [action="' + reference + '"]' + 
    ', [class="' + reference + '"]' +

);
```

...and so on